# getting error on wpdb line wordpress

Tags: wordpress

getting error $wodb as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
function store_db() { 
    global $wpdb; $fields = array('email');
     $tbl_name = $wpdb->prefix.'feedback';  
    $kv_data = array(   's_email'=> $email) ; 
     $wpdb->insert( $tbl_name, $kv_data )      
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using an IDE such as Sublime Text, DreamWeaver, PHP Storm, etc. Any number of them would show you where the syntax error is. I pasted it into my IDE and it instantly told me there was a missing semi colon after this line `$wpdb->insert( $tbl_name, $kv_data )`.

Also you'll want to take care to manage your formatting/indentation - future you appreciates it!

```
function store_db() { 
    global $wpdb;

    $field   = array( 'email' );
    $table   = $wpdb->prefix.'feedback';
    $kv_data = array( 's_email' => $email );

    $wpdb->insert( $table, $kv_data ); // Added `;` to this line.
}
```